# geom and ggplot. Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (11): x, y, ymin, ymax

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IhMm.png) I'm using this script to try to creat a figure like this
I'm using the data and script bellow, but the following message has appeared:

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (11): x, y, ymin, ymax

```css
The output of dput(graf1)is:
structure(list(est = structure(c(10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 11L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E ", "F", "G", 
"H", "I ", "Intercept   ", "J"), class = "factor"), min = c(-2.59987657, 
1.90207329, 0.19540912, 0.38539491, 0.44573408, -0.62036798, 
-0.25411668, 0.12885761, -1.11518838, -0.08929551, -0.07907754
), max = c(-2.12964144, 2.31358683, 0.34741113, 0.53284866, 0.6833492, 
-0.32613644, 0.12285579, 0.46712478, -0.48094942, 0.05204147, 
0.06417294)), .Names = c("est", "min", "max"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

```r
script
graf1 <- read.csv(file="tab.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
str(graf1)
attach(graf1)
names(graf1)
dput(graf1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(graf1, aes(x=graf1$X, y=graf1$est, ymin=graf1$min,ymax=graf1$max))+
  geom_pointrange()+
  geom_point()+
  coord_flip()+geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dotted")+ 
  xlab('Variable')
```

```r
est min max
Intercept       -2.59987657 -2.12964144
A   1.90207329  2.31358683
B   0.19540912  0.34741113
C   0.38539491  0.53284866
D   0.44573408  0.6833492
E   -0.62036798 -0.32613644
F   -0.25411668 0.12285579
G   0.12885761  0.46712478
H   -1.11518838 -0.48094942
I   -0.08929551 0.05204147
J   -0.07907754 0.06417294
```

Comment: Does `graf1` have a column named `X`? It does not appear so from the data that you have pasted. Can you run `dput(graf1)` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: 1) don't `attach`; 2) `ggplot(graf1, aes(x = X, y = est, ymin = min, ymax = max)) +` is simpler; 3) what @WeihuangWong said, there is no `X` in your posted dataset.

Comment: Presumably the `est` in your dataframe is really what you mean by `X`. Then where is the data for `est` (the points) in your dataframe? You only have `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only min and max values, about the best you can do is `geom_linerange`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(est = c("Intercept", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), 
                 min = c(-2.59987657, 1.90207329, 0.19540912, 0.38539491, 0.44573408, -0.62036798, -0.25411668, 0.12885761, -1.11518838, -0.08929551, -0.07907754),
                 max = c(-2.12964144, 2.31358683, 0.34741113, 0.53284866, 0.6833492, -0.32613644, 0.12285579, 0.46712478, -0.48094942, 0.05204147, 0.06417294))

ggplot(df, aes(factor(est, levels = rev(est)), ymin = min, ymax = max)) + 
    geom_linerange() + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dotted") + 
    coord_flip() + 
    labs(x = 'Variable')
```

[image: linerange coef plot]

Comment: You could do that, e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(est, (min + max) / 2, ymin = min, ymax = max)) + geom_pointrange() + coord_flip()`, but usually those points in these plots represent an actual estimate, not just the midpoint of the line, as sometimes intervals can be asymmetric.

Comment: Alistaire, thank you very much for your answer. However I have other doubt. I was considering geom_point () because I wanted to mark through a point the the median between the maximum and minimum values. As the figure in the link below. Would you also have a suggestion for this? Thanks strengejacke.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/lmer1.png

Comment: `geom_pointrange` is (more or less) shorthand for `geom_linerange(...) + geom_point(...)`. (`geom_linerange` itself is a restricted version of `geom_segment`.) You can always recreate these things from their component parts, or add extra points, or customize as you like. That said, your visualization should present your data honestly, and if the points you're adding aren't parameter estimates, you need to make that clear, as this plot (a "caterpillar plot") is commonly used for plotting estimates with error intervals.